i am writing groovy . i have problem with formatting (forced) groovy template engine
i am writing groovy . i have problem with formatting (forced) groovy template engine.
groovy template engine forces my xml to format
<tag>string</tag>

it turns it to
<tag>
    string
</tag>

i dont want my xml will be changed
the code :
def text=new File(filePath).text
def engine = new groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine()

def template = engine.createTemplate(text).make(binding)

def xmlString = template.toString()

i want to avoid groovy to format my xml

try to use SimpleTemplateEngine instead

i have logic in my xml template :
gsp:scriptlet
if(name=="Str"){
</gsp:scriptlet>

I know it's not the question, but both outputs are the same as far as XML is concerned

there are 2 options: by default it's formatted, or you can turn off formatting : new XmlTemplateEngine( configurePrinter: { it.preserveWhitespace = true } ), however it will not preserve your original format
